# Raymers Installed engine equation

Tags: aircraft-design

I am currently modelling an aero engine and require the weight breakdown of the individual components, I have the dry weight of the engine and need to verify the pylon and nacelle weight.

Raymer has presented an equation for the weight of the installed engine in his book 
W installed engine = 2.575 *W engine^0.922*Nengine.

Does this include the pylon ?

Comment: That's an interesting question, +1, but you should provide some details (in which study or book), and also explain why you're unsure, in spite of having read the study.

Comment: It would help if you would post the equation that you're asking about.

Comment: I can see that you want an answer. But how significant would your error be either way?